# Error in optim(init[mask], armaCSS, method = optim.method, hessian = FALSE, : non-finite value supplied by optim

Tags: r

Hi I'm trying to build a Arima forecast using multiple exogenous variables in my R 4.0.2. My exogenous variables are binary & contain 0 and 1 only. I wrote following code

```
z=Arima(train$Util,order=c(2,1,2),xreg=as.matrix(train[,c(6,7)]))
```

I'm getting the error message

```
Error in optim(init[mask], armaCSS, method = optim.method, hessian = FALSE,  : 
non-finite value supplied by optim
```

My data is looking like

```
Date    Util  ... ... ... Weekdays  Weenend
 1      0.425  ... ... ...     1       0
 2      0.351  ... ... ...     1       0
 3      0.382  ... ... ...     1       0
 4      0.451  ... ... ...     1       0
 5      0.421  ... ... ...     1       0
 6      0.701  ... ... ...     0       1
 7      0.752  ... ... ...     0       1
```

I'm seeing maximum utilization during week end so I have created two variables weekdays & weekend & trying to incorporate them in my Arima
Can you help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Hi, it would be more helpful if you could share the content of the `train` variable. This way the community here will be able to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Added in my original post

Comment: A better way to share your data is to use the `dput()` function. If you data is stored in the variable `my_data` for example, you can run `dput(my_data)` and then share the output with us. If `my_data` is too big, then you can select a certain number of rows to share. For example: `dput(my_data[1:50, ])`. Having said that, are `Weekdays` and `Weekend` the 6th and 7th columns of the `train` variable?

Comment: In any case, by looking at what you posted, I can tell that the issue you are encountering comes from the nature of your `Util` column. You have to transform it into a `numeric` column. Once you share a piece of your data, I will show you how to do that.

Comment: @SavedByJESUS, sorry my bad. I have written util column wrongly. It's in numeric format. I have corrected it in my original post. str(train) is showing  `Util: num`

Comment: It seems you did not see my message before the one you answered.

Comment: @SavedByJESUS, yes 6th & 7th columns are dummy variable for weekdays & weekend. I can't able to give you data using dupt() as it's client data.I have given you cooked data as an example

Comment: This is perfectly understandable, but what I mean is that even if you have cooked data, you should share it in a format that can be easily used by the people who read your question.

Comment: In any case, I did not really pay too much attention to your data, but when I did I realized that your weekdays and weekend columns are perfectly correlated. So this will not work! You just need one of the two columns, not both.